# Deployment to heroku failed - Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push a rails website to heroku but keep getting an error rake aborted! 
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome. (sass):7025
Precompiling assets failed. 
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

The app run perfect local. I'm new to rails so all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147328/rails-compiler-error-with-fontawesome-when-deploy-to-heroku try to follow this; there are so much questions about this problems try to search first before asking questions

Comment: Okay - this is strange.... I added `code` @import "font-awesome"; to application.scss and gem 'font-awesome-sass' to my gem file... and boom it works... Funny thing is that local I also need `code` @import "font-awesome"; in my application.css file... but now it works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Engine - File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356062/rails-engine-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-font-awesome)

Answer (score 1):

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

Then try again

Answer (score 0):

Okay - this is strange.... I added code @import "font-awesome"; to application.scss and gem 'font-awesome-sass' to my gem file... and boom it works... Funny thing is that local I also need code @import "font-awesome"; in my application.css file... but now it works..